# Run time check of ARC (Automatic Reference Counting)

Tags: objective-c, ios4, automatic-ref-counting

How can I check if my program is running in an ARC (Automatic Reference Counting) device?

I can use this code:

```
#if ! __has_feature(objc_arc)
#    define FMDBRelease(__v) ([__v release]);
#else
#    define FMDBRelease(__v)
#endif
```

But this work in compile time. A easy code for this is:

```
if ([object respondsToSelector:@selector(release)]) {
    [object release];
}
```

But not work. I am not finding it in any place. There are a solution for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. ARC is a compile-time tool. It has no real presence at runtime, except for the insertion of calls that allow for tail-call optimization.

Answer (score 5):

ARC is a compile time technology, thus the `#if __has_feature(objc_arc)` way is the correct way of doing this.